# bootstrap table out of screen when body has padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I have a boostrap table.
I want to have a padding on the entire page so I put:

```
body {
  padding: 70px 20px;
}
```

But after I do it, the table "ignores" the padding - and makes it 20px wider than the screen (and adds a horizontal scroll)

How can I tell bootstrap table "You have 20px less on each side" - calculate accordingly

**Edit:**
I made a JSBin for you guys to help me more easily - and on it everything works....
grrrr....
http://jsbin.com/becivuramu

I'm using Ember.js, bootstrap-sass latest (3.3.1)
I compared the styles of the resulting tables, and besides width related stuff (duh) everything is exactly the same

I don't see anything out of the ordinary - anyone has a hunch on where to look?

Comment: Have you checked whether it happens with a regular non-Bootstrap `<table>`?

Comment: well... a regular `<table>` is not responsive and fits/doesn't fit the screen - so it misses the point

Answer (score 0):

I ended up wrapping the entire hbs in a div container and setting it's padding and not `<body>`'s.
Not sure why but the ember divs on the way mess up setting `<body>`'s padding